# Pathlib joining absolute path together

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

I'm trying to join two path together, the second starts with a leading slash.

```py
from pathlib  import Path

path = Path('/first', '/second')

# outputs WindowsPath('/second')
# expecting WindowsPath('/first/second')
print(path)
```

From the example above, you can see it removes the first path.

While it's not a big deal to use something like `removeprefix('/')`, I'm curious to know why it's behaving this way. Is there is a builtin way to change this behaviour?

Comment: from the doc _"if a segment is an absolute path, all previous segments are ignored"_

Comment: You have given pathlib an absolute path, and it's treating it like an absolute path.  It's doing exactly what it's supposed to.  If you don't want an absolute path, then remove the '/' before turning it into a path.

Comment: In my case, this values comes from an api, I cannot control how it's being passed to me. As said in the question, `removeprefix` can be used.

Comment: You could define your own "macro": `def remove_root(path:Path):
    if path.is_absolute():
        return Path().joinpath(*path.parts[1:])
    return path

new_p = p1 / remove_root(p2)`

Answer (score 0):

An absolute path is by definition fully qualified and it's not possible to add two absolute paths, which is why the behavior makes sense, the last absolute path overrides anything before it.

When dealing with virtual paths a convenience function like this is helpful:

```
def join_paths(*args: Path):
    """Concatenate paths even if some paths are absolute"""
    return Path(args[0], *[str(arg).lstrip('/') for arg in args[1:]])
```